# A regex pattern '{.*}' does not work in Vim as (I) expected

Tags: regex, vim

I have a one-line text file opened in Vim:

```
a{b} {c}
```

I want to match strings enclosed by curly braces. If my cursor is at line 1 col 1 of the file and I do

```
:call search('{.*}', 'W')
```

The cursor will go to the first '{' after the character 'a'.

But if I repeat the search, the cursor does not go to the second '{' which is between 'b' and 'c', and `echo search('{.*}', 'W')` returns 0.

Why?

EDIT: Let me address the answer by @romainl

I understand that `*` is greedy, and I am OK matching `{b} {c}` first.

However, when the cursor is under the first `{`, the pattern should still be able to match `{c}` because `{c}` is after the cursor and agrees with the pattern.

Comment: `echo search('{.*}', 'W')` will return `0` if the cursor is not on or before the possible match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

romainl is right, vim apparently doesn't ignore the characters before the cursor when using search().

If you still wanna use a greedy operator inside the braces you can do this

```
echo search('\m\%#.\{-1,}\zs{.*}', 'W')
```

`\%#` matches only after the cursor position, `.\{-1,}` makes sure we match anything AFTER the first { if we're on it, `\zs` excludes these from the actual match

Answer (score 1):

`*` is greedy, it will match *as many* instances of the previous pattern as possible. This means that `{.*}` will match this:

```
a{b} {c}
 ^^^^^^^
```

instead of the desired:

```
a{b} {c}
 ^^^
```

You should use a non-greedy pattern like `\{-}`:

```
{.\{-}}
```

which will match:

```
a{b} {c}
 ^^^
```

and:

```
a{b} {c}
     ^^^
```

on next call.

When trying to find the right search pattern, it is generally useful to do so on the command-line with `'incsearch'` on. Try it with your original pattern and you will immediately see what is wrong.

See `:help pattern-multi-items` and `:help \{`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have replied to it in my original post.

Comment: You don't get it. `{.*}` matches *everything* from the first `{` on the line to the last `}` on the line. There is only *one* match on the line so further calls do nothing.

Comment: I assume the way Vim matches patterns works depends on the position of the cursor. When I call a search, Vim ignores the substring from the beginning of the current line up to the cursor, and looks for a match after the cursor. For example if my cursor is under the first `a` of a line `c acab` and I search for `a`, then Vim would treat it as a match for `a` in the substring `cab`. So this is not the case?

Comment: If your cursor is already on a match, Vim will start searching after that match. So there is no way to jump to a second match inside the current match, because vim skips over the entire first match.

Comment: @Ben Ah I see, and romainl's comment also makes sense to me now. Thanks to both!